# Java: Could you explain this simple statement (System.out.println)?

Tags: java

```
System.out.println(1 + 2 + "3");
```

Output:
33

```
System.out.println("1" + 2 + 3);
```

Output:
123

Comment: Somewhat related question here for .NET developers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517695

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Well, it's a thing called order of operations.

1 + 2 is calculated to equal 3 and then the string "3" is appended to it converting the first 3 to a string and printing "33".

In your second instance, "1" is already a string so adding numbers will convert them to strings to match, so appending "2" and then appending "3" and printing "123".

P.S. Strings take precedence because they have a higher casting priority than integers do, therefore it will convert integers to strings but not strings to integers, as with the second example.

Comment: +1 Ewww. Implicit casting in C#. I thought C# was supposed to be a purely statically typed language.</sarcasm>

Comment: @EvanPlaice: This is Java?

Answer (score 7):

The first statement adds 1 and 2 (since both are Integers) and then converts them to a string and appends the string "3".

The second statement has a string "1" and converts all following arguments to strings as well. So you get 123.

Answer (score 6):

In the case of `1 + 2 + "3"`

Addition of 1 and 2 is performed first next 3 is concatenated to 3.

In `"1" + 2 + 3`

1 is concatenated to 2 and the result ("12") is concatenated to 3

The thing to remember is:

> **If either of the operands to + is a string + acts as concatenation else it works as addition.**

Answer (score 3):

In case of first , it does 1+2 ,  then it does the string concatenation operation , So that it gives you 33.

In case of second statement it is doing string concatenation for all operand   , since first

operand is string. So that it gives you 123

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a java expert but I suppose expressions are read from left to right here

In the first case it first compute 1 + 3 which gives 3 
then 3 + "3" which convert the first 3 to a string and gives "33"

In the second case it starts by "1" + 2 which gives "12"
and then "12" + 3 = "123"

This is a side effect of having an operator + which concatenates 2 strings and an other which adds 2 numbers.

Answer (score 3):

This is defined by the [Java Language Specification #15.18.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)

> The + operator is syntactically left-associative, no matter whether it is determined by type analysis to represent string concatenation or numeric addition. In some cases care is required to get the desired result. For example, the expression:
>   `a + b + c`
>   is always regarded as meaning:
>   `(a + b) + c`

Then for each subgroup `(a+b)` (let's call it `x`) and `(x + c)`:

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will convert an operand to its string equivalent whenever the other operand
of the **+** is an instance of **String**.

**For the second case:** Operator precedence causes the concatenation of "1" with the string equivalent of 2 to take place first. This result is then concatenated with the string equivalent of 3 a second time.

To complete the integer addition first, you must use parentheses, like this:

```
System.out.println("1" + (2 + 3));
```

**For the first case:** Operator precedence will first add 1 and 2. Now,string equivalent of this result is then concatenated with "3".

Answer (score 0):

system.out.println(-1>>>1);

For the second case: Operator precedence causes the concatenation of "1" with the string equivalent of 2 to take place first. This result is then concatenated with the string equivalent of 3 a second time.

To complete the integer addition first, you must use parentheses, like this:

Answer (score 0):

In 1st case 1 and 2 treated as integer so the answer is 3 and next + concatenate the result with string 3.
In 2nd case "1" is a string and sop treat every thing as  string after appearing a string ie "2" and "3" also act as  strings so all get concatenate to show output 123