# C#: how to construct strings

Tags: c#, string, casting

Which of these will achieve the correct result:

(1)

```
int X = 23;
string str = "HELLO" + X.ToString() + "WORLD";
```

(2)

```
int X = 23;
string str = "HELLO" + X + "WORLD";
```

(3)

```
int X = 23;
string str = "HELLO" + (string)X + "WORLD";
```

EDIT: The 'correct' result is for `str` to evaluate to: HELLO23WORLD

Comment: I have to say it, What is the correct result?

Comment: Well, except for the fact that there's no such thing as `toString()` in C#, it's `ToString()`.

Comment: Try it and see. You've got a compiler handy, don't you? You'd quickly recognize a typo in the first version if you did. In any event, Darin's answer is better.

Comment: You realize 1 won't compile (type, ToString() needs to be capitalized) and 3 will give you an invalid cast exception, right?

Comment: @R0MANARMY: OK, so you're saying the answer can't be 3.

Comment: @Craig Johnston: I ran 3 in Linqpad as a sanity check and got an error, so yes, I'm pretty sure it can't be 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 3 doesn't compile cause you cannot cast an `int` to `string`.

The two others produce the same result. However, there's a subtle difference.

Internally the plus operator compiles to a call to `String.Concat`. `Concat` has different overloads. Option 1 calls `Concat(string, string, string)` while option 2 calls `Concat(object, object, object)` with two strings and a boxed int. Internally `Concat` then calls `ToString` on the boxed int.

Also, check this related question: [Strings and ints, implicit and explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517695/strings-and-ints-implicit-and-explicit)

Comment: Why doesn't option 2 call ToString() on the int and use the Concat(string, string, string) overload?

Comment: I would assume that it is because it makes code generation for the caller simpler by letting the Concat method do all the work.

Answer (score 7):

```
int X = 23;
string str = string.Format("HELLO{0}WORLD", X);
```

Comment: Please leave a comment when down-voting. Is there something wrong with my answer?

Comment: -1: the question asked which of the three code segments produced a correct result, but your answer is still useful because it shows an alternative method, but it is not answering the question

Comment: +1: **much** better than concatenating strings. It feels wrong that the answerer got penalized simply because he did not explain why it is a better option than the 3 posted in the question.

Comment: The question asked which of the three was correct. Creating a fourth option is not a valid answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use StringBuilder too:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder str = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
str.Append("HELLO"); 
str.Append(X); 
str.Append("World");
```